# How to save maximum find value in text file in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection am trying to find maximum salary from json file imported in this collection, how can i do that using command line

```
db.collectionName.find().sort({salary:-1}).limit(1)
```

after running above cmd I am getting some record but I need to save it in txt.file

Comment: I guess you can use spy object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748224/how-to-test-http-post-request-with-parameters-in-angular-9

Answer (score 0):

I can share with you an example of unit test for HTTP post request:

```
  it('should send selected request', () => {
   const bodyObjec: Model={
... Your data
}
        yourService.methodPost(stagingArea as Required<Model>).subscribe();
    
        const { request } = httpMock.expectOne('../api/accounts/${accountId}/bank/selected');
        expect(request.method).toBe('POST');
        expect(request.body).toEqual(bodyObject);
      });
```